# How to save OAuth2 access token in Client / Browser when calling Resource APIs with Bearer token as Authorization Header

Tags: angular, spring, oauth-2.0, jwt, keycloak

I have an Angular Application where I am using **Keycloak (OAuth2 provider) Login Page**. Once I login with username and password in the Login page, I am getting auth code and with that code I am calling Keycloak Token Generator API `http://localhost:8080/realms/CloudBrokerRealm/protocol/openid-connect/token` and getting access token & refresh token successfully. No issues till getting the tokens.

Now I need to store the access & refresh tokens in Client side so that I can send the bearer access token in Authorization Header for calling my backend Rest APIs (**Resource APIs created with Java, Spring Boot, Spring Security**).

After searching many links on internet I can see some people are suggesting to store token in httpOnly cookie intead of local storage or session storage on browser. But I am not able to store the tokens in httpOnly cookie as Keycloak sends the tokens in Response Body, not as cookie when calling Keycloak Token Generator API mentioned above. I can't set the cookie (httpOnly) from javascript / angular after extracting the tokens from response body as it is not possible.

So my questions are:

1. How to store the OAuth2 access & refresh token in Client side which will be required to call some backend Rest APIs (Resource APIs) with Bearer Token as 'Authorization' header.
2. If we store it in httpOnly cookie, how we will send the Token as 'Authorization' header as our Rest API will expect that mandatory header.

Comment: Don’t store access token in localStorage/cookie, only store refresh, keep access token in a service (memory) and add it to api calls as needed. This is the easiest way to go about it, look into interceptors as it’s a solid way to catch errors and call refresh when you need a new access token.

Comment: Hi Levidps, If I keep access token in a service (memory) in UI (Angular) code, then all the components can access the token from service class? Also if yes, then if user reloads the browser, how would they get the access token from the service, as service will not have the stored data after browser reload/refresh?

Comment: In the past I’ve always refreshed the access token on browser/page reload as the refresh token is the only one stored in the browser. I’ve done it using an interceptor to check if the service has access token and if not or if the token is about to expire then it fetches a new one.

Comment: Thanks Levidps. It is working with the suggestions you provided. But for multiple applications when I will use SSO, will this work? I mean if I save the access token in memory in one app, how it will be accessible by another app in different browser tab in case of SSO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current best practices are described in [OAuth 2.0 for Browser Based Apps](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps). Section 6.2 describes how cookie to token translation is usually done, via a backend for frontend.

Tokens cannot be stored fully securely in the browser. The perception is likely to be that an app using tokens in Javascript has greater security concerns, eg ways to intercept and exfiltrate them.

A cookie implementation for SPAs usually involves an API gateway that manages translating between cookies and tokens. It is a whole extra deployment layer though, so requires design and planning.

**URLs**

One option is to use a web backend at a URL like this to be the OAuth client and to issue cookies. This is really a website, but some people find this option simplest:

- https://www.example.com (web backend)

SPA solutions that separate web and API concerns can instead use three URLs like this, all hosted behind an API gateway:

- https://www.example.com (static content)
- https://www.example.com/api (API routes)
- https://www.example.com/oauth (the OAuth client that issues cookies)

Comment: Thanks Gary for the info. So if I have a API Gateway, I can receive the token in cookie in API Gateway and set that token in Authorization Header before passing the request to the API from API Gateway. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes - that's right. The API gateway should be able to run logic such as decrypting tokens encrypted into cookies if required. Some gateways support this via scripting in languages such as LUA. Eg OpenResty or Kong Open Source.

Comment: Thanks Gary for the suggestion. I have accepted your answer. One last thing, I am using Angular as Frontend and Spring Boot Java application along with API Gateway as backend. Shall I need  to make Backend API Gateway as OAuth client so that it will redirect the user to Auth server (e.g. Keycloak) Login Page and generate the token in API Gateway OR shall I redirect user to Auth server (e.g. Keycloak) Login Page from Frontend (e.g. Angular) and make API Gateway as OAuth resource instead of OAuth client so that it only verifies the access token while getting the API Request. Which is better?

Comment: It kind of depends on your preferences and what you have already. I added a section to my answer. Usually the API routes are implemented in the gateway, and the OAuth client as a utility component.

Comment: Thanks Gary. I have noticed your added section in the answer. So you mean to say, I can write a separate Service in backend which will be dedicated to Security (OAuth2 etc) and which will redirect the user to OAuth2 Login Page and act as a OAuth2 Client? So I will have Frontend App, Backend API Gateway for routes, dedicated Backend Service which will be my OAuth2 client and some other services which will have the actual Resources (Rest APIs). Is my understanding correct?

Comment: That's it - it's how I would build an API driven solution. You may find some open source components that do the security work for you ...

Answer (score 0):

Don't implement authorization code (with PKCE) flow by yourself. Use [a certified OIDC client library](https://openid.net/developers/certified/).

My favorite for Angular is [angular-auth-oidc-client](https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client).

It will handle

- redirections to authorization-server
- exchange of authorization code for tokens
- silent token refreshing just before it expires
- auto login with Angular route guard
- request Authorization (position access token in requests header) with HTTP interceptor
- ...

All that with just a little conf.

Comment: Not entirely true, yes this makes sense for integration with existing auth flows. However if someone were building a full stack application including DB and user creation then it might not be best to use a 3rd party lib.

Comment: The question clearly references an OIDC authorization-server: Keycloak (which is totally compatible with apps including DB and user creation). In case of standard OAuth2, this is none sens to re-invent the wheel (not sure and expensive), so yes, use a certified client lib: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://openid.net/developers/certified/&ved=2ahUKEwi-icjkv_n7AhWkMUQIHfmpC44QFnoECB4QAQ&usg=AOvVaw0QO1jLCMfpvzi5b_r2DwJK

Comment: Thanks ch4mp. But if I use OIDC client library, then where the library will store the access token and refresh token? Is it in some cookies or local storage or in some angular variable (in memory)  etc. ? I just want to know that info.

Comment: That could change (a bit) from a lib to another, but access and ID token should live in memory only (either of the app or a worker, as explained in the document linked by Gary Archer). Ideally, the refresh token is not accessible to the Dom (secure HTTP cookie accessible only tby the authorization-server is an option). Refer to the documentation of the lib you choose for details.